# dotnet cli how to create project using previous sdk/framework?

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli

Let's say that I'm using Core 3.0 with Blazor templates installed

My VS  updated and downloaded sdk `3.1 preview X` and now my dotnet cli works in `3.1 preview` by default

so using `dotnet new` doesn't show my installed Blazor templates  that I installed while using `3.0`

I tried those commands to at least see name of previous templates or actually create `3.0` Blazor project, but nothing works

```sh
dotnet new --sdk-version "3.0.100-preview7-012821"
dotnet new --framework "netcoreapp3.0"

# Invalid input switch:--sdk-version3.0.100-preview7-012821
```

How can I list `dotnet new` templates for previous sdk/framework and then actually create them?

Comment: The error message says that you forgot to type a space after --sdk-version.  Hmm.

Comment: @HansPassant Console output formats it quite differently, the part after `:` is in newline with `space` before, so I doubt it. `dotnet new --sdk-version "3.0.100-preview7-012821"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the docs on how to [select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version):

Create a `global.json` file in your new project folder with the following content (for .net core 2.2.203 - change to required version):

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.203"
  }
}
```

From a command line `cd` into that folder and run:
`dotnet new choose-template-name`

Running any dotnet CLI command in this folder and sub-folders, will use the specified SDK.

Make sure the SDK is installed first, of course.

Comment: Use this command to check the specific API versions you have installed: `dotnet --list-sdks`